# AS3 - Can I know if a class implements an interface (or is a subclass of another class)?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, class

With this code

```
function someFunction(classParam:Class):Boolean
{
    // how to know if classParam implements some interface?
}
```

i.e. Comparing `classParam` with `IEventDispatcher` interface:

```
someFunction(EventDispatcher) // returns true
someFunction(Object) // returns false
```

I know it can't be done with `is` operator. But, is there a way to do it? Is there a way to know if a class implements some interface? (or is a subclass of another class?)

Possible solutions:

A. Creating an object of `classParam` and using that object to compare using `is` operator.

```
function someFunction(classParam:Class):Boolean
{
    return (new classParam()) is IEventDispatcher
}
```

B. Using `describeType()`

```
function someFunction(classParam:Class):Boolean
{
    var xml:XML = describeType(classParam)
    // found "implementsInterface" value in xml and compare to IEventDispatcher
}
```

There is a way that DOES NOT USE `describeType` or creates a `new` operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any way to achieve what you're trying to do except by using `describeType`.
It has been created for this purpose, why don't you want to use it?

Edit:
It actually only takes 2 lines to do this :

```
var classDescription:XML = describeType(classParam);
return (classDescription.factory.implementsInterface.(@type == getQualifiedClassName(IEventDispatcher)).length() != 0);
```

...or just in one, if it's what bothers you:

```
return (describeType(classParam).factory.implementsInterface.(@type == getQualifiedClassName(IEventDispatcher)).length() != 0);
```

Comment: What bothers me is the speed of `describeType`. Isn't it slow?

Comment: It depends of how much you are using it, but yes, it's pretty slow. Problem is I don't think there's another way to achieve this. This article may interest you, the author made a benchmark and found out that a describeType on UIComponent takes 5ms on his computer: http://faindu.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/actionscript-flex-dependency-injection-performance/

Comment: So creating the object will take less time? I will run a benchmark on that to see it.

Comment: Here is the benchmark: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2283327/stackoverflow/describeTypeBenchmark/describeTypeBenchmark.html

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark, results are very interesting. And it proves that describeType is indeed _really_ slow =/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to 'Zed-K' response.  I ended up not needing the .factory part.  Here is a example of a test that checks that the class is utilizing and interface.  '_instance' is the class under test.

```
[Test]
public function testInstanceShouldBeIUser():void
{
    var classDescription:XML = describeType( _instance );
    var type:String = getQualifiedClassName(IUser);
    var xmlList:XMLList = classDescription.implementsInterface.(@type == type);
    assertTrue("expected IUser", xmlList.length() != 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Btw, there is also `describeTypeJSON`, witch is about 5x faster than `describeType`.