# How to test if a class reference implements an interface?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How can I test if a class reference implements an interface?

Note that the is and instanceof operators do not work with Class references.

Example:

```
    public function set someClassref(value:Class):void
    {   
        if(value is IMyInterface)
        {
            _someClassref = value;
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AS3 - Can I know if a class implements an interface (or is a subclass of another class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518180/as3-can-i-know-if-a-class-implements-an-interface-or-is-a-subclass-of-another) has what appear to be the two most common solutions.

Comment: Was hoping I wouldn't have to instantiate it. Guess I have no other choice.

Comment: Check out the `describeType`-based solution in the same post. They say it's a bit slower, but it won't require an instance.